# Display None on Select Option based on the data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I actually have a multiple dropdown. what I want is, if I select the `first` dropdown and I have the `data-ts` which is 1. I want that all of my dropdown option that has a data-ts 1 to have a style attribute display none except for the one that I selected.

here's what I have done so far:

**HTML**

```
<select class="selection" name="first">
 <option value="1" data-ts="1">1</option>
 <option value="2" data-ts="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="selection" name="second">
<option value="3" data-ts="1">1</option>
<option value="4" data-ts="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="selection" name="third">
<option value="5" data-ts="1">1</option>
<option value="6" data-ts="2">2</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".selection").on('change', function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        var $selected = $this.find(":selected").data('ts');

        $(".selected").each(function(){
            alert($(this).val());
        });

    });
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $(".selection").on('change', function() {

  var $this = $(this);

  var $selected = $this.find(":selected").data('ts');
  console.log($selected);
  var i = 0;
  var array = [];
      $(".selection").each(function() {

            if($this.attr('name')!= $(this).attr('name'))
            {
                if($(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-ts') == $selected)
                {
                       $(this).val('');
                }
            }

            if($(this).find("option:selected").data('ts') != 'undifined' )
            {
                 array[i] = $(this).find("option:selected").data('ts');
                 i = i+1;
            }
      });



     $(".selection").each(function() {
               if($(this).val()=='')
               {
                   $(this).find("option").show();
                   for(j=0;j<array.length;j++)
                   {
                       $(this).find("option[data-ts='" + array[j] + "']").hide();    
                   }

               }


      });



});
```

JSFiddle link for same

https://jsfiddle.net/0y8L4y1e/5/

Comment: Hi sir this is the closest... I do have issue though... forexample if you try to select 2 on the first dropdown.. the second and third dropdown should have 1 as a remaining option.

Comment: there's still a bug sir... the user can leave the first dropdown blank and go directly to 2nd and 3rd... if that is the case 1st dropdown should not have a option.

Comment: Please check my solution is already working fine for that case

Comment: Hi sir there is still a bug... go try and select on the third dropdown then try select on the first...

Comment: @SamTengWong Now you can check my solution for your query

Comment: Hi sir.. thank you very much.... I happen to solve the problem too by disabling the option instead of hiding them... but you nailed it.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You have to check if data-ts is equal to the selected data-ts and that the option you want to hide IS NOT the option you just selected.

```
$(".selection").on('change', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $selected = $this.find(":selected");
    var selectedTsData = $selected.data('ts');

    $(".selection option").each(function () {
        $(this).show();
        if ($(this).data('ts') === selectedTsData && $(this) !== $selected) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
$(".selection").on('change', function() {
  $(".selection").each(function() {
    $(this).find("option").show();

  });
  var $this = $(this);
  var $selected = $this.find(":selected").data('ts');
  console.log($selected)
  $(".selection").each(function() {
    $(this).find("option[data-ts='" + $selected + "']").hide();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selection" name="first">
<option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="1" data-ts="1">1</option>
 <option value="2" data-ts="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="selection" name="second">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="3" data-ts="1">1</option>
<option value="4" data-ts="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="selection" name="third">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="5" data-ts="1">1</option>
<option value="6" data-ts="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi sir... the 3rd dropdown should have no option left based on the first and second dropdown selected options. if I select 1 on first dropdown and 2 on the second dropdown..

Comment: Do you expect to select options in order? first select first and so on or it is random order?

Comment: depends on the user.. if the user select 2 on the first dropdown the remaining dropdowns should have only 1 as option and if I select 1 on the second dropdown the third dropdown will not have any option at all... since first and second dropdown use it.